# How to center text below image using relative layout

Tags: android

I have 4 ImageViews, and 4 TextViews,

How can I center each textview below its respective imageview?

When I do layoutToRightOf it puts the text views next to each other

Comment: Please post your current Layout XML, so we can adjust it of find the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this using the drawableTop feature of textview...